# How can I reuse django form for searching?

Tags: python, django, forms

I am programming an application in django, and I have a model where I defined some fields that are necessary to be filled. This way, when te user doesn't fill one of these fields, Django authomatically indicates to the user to fill it to create the specific object defined by the model.

But myquestion comes here: I want to reuse the same form to search objects defined by that model. And in this case, all the fields that before were necessary, now are OPTIONAL. But, as I have already defined the model so that the fields are necessary, django doesn´t let me define those fields as optional.

Is there any way to reuse that form where the fields are necessary, but making them OPTIONAL? Or I must create another different model or form in html? I know that creating another form manually in the html code the problem is solver, but I have curiosity to know if it can be reused.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically change properties of a field within a form using its `fields` dictionary. So you could create a new form class that is derived from your current form class and in its `__init__` set the `required` property of the fields you desired to be optional to be `False` like so:

```
self.fields['title'].required = False
```

Comment: For example, if I have this form and I have a field title in model Ensaioa, how can I change the requirement to false?                 : class EnsaioBilaketaFormularioa(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Ensaioa